# How can I make the columns equal height, despite the content inside it?

Tags: html, css

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/minacosentino/pen/wrWxXV)

I must use only CSS for this also. For this specific layout, I have columns created as such:

```
<div class="col-md-12 no-border no-padding">
  <h2 class="heading upper align-center">Headline</h2>
  <p class="subheading lower align-center">Make the first thing your buyers see amazing</p>
  <div class="help-link align-center upper margin-b-5">
    <p class="mini-help">Need help? Watch this&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div class="help">
      <div class="hvr-grow"><i class="icon-camrecorder"></i></div>
    </div>
    <p class="mini-help upper align-center margin b-5">&nbsp;&nbsp;quick video.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that you have implemented the `.row-eq-height` to set the height of all columns equal, but you have missed that there is another `.col-md-12` inside each column, which takes the width of the content inside it, so just set it to `height:100%` for it to take the height of the parent instead!

<kbd>**Codepen Demo**</kbd>

**CSS Change:**

```
.headlines .row-eq-height > div > .col-md-12{
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly - and totally overlooked the nested columns. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Already answered, but i still go with my answer .

I did not touch HTML nor your CSS but I added a few selectors and flex rules to make every boxes on a row of the same height. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wrJWMq

/* CSS UPDATE */

```
div.row,
.row > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.row > div {
  flex-flow: column;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.row > div > div {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}

.multi-summ.align-center.bcolor-white {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```